# How to synchronize my datacontexts with external DB changes?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-4

Say I have multiple panels, some of them showing data from DB, and some others allowing to add/delete/update rows in DB.
I also have another program (on another computer) able to write in DB at the same time.

I don't have any middleware server between each program, which I found overkill given the small size of my project (my mistake ? maybe, but I was afraid of the time it would have taken).

How can I have my ViewModels refresh accordingly to DB changes on the fly ?
All properties would be up to date each time the vm is reinstanciated, which happens... nearly never.

I've been told SQL Server has mechanisms that could help me. Does it involve triggers ?
I need a little help and advice here.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Notification is an option. Check this link out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx

Here is a straightforward example of how to implement it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(VS.80).aspx

However, despite the example please note the [caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) of using this in client applications

> SqlDependency was designed to be used
>   in ASP.NET or middle-tier services
>   where there is a relatively small
>   number of servers having dependencies
>   active against the database. It was
>   not designed for use in client
>   applications, where hundreds or
>   thousands of client computers would
>   have SqlDependency objects set up for
>   a single database server.